# C# Assigning default value to System.Uri property

Tags: c#, properties

I have a project which is about RESTful API and I have as a property the basic URL, on which I need to add parts each time (that's in my methods). I need (a) to declare the default (unchanged) path, and then (b) some help on how do I add to the URL. Example:

```
    public partial class APIParamaters
{
    public System.Uri URL { get; set; } = (System.Uri) "http://192.100.106.657:8811/some/part/here/version1/api";   //throws error !!!
}
```

This is throwing an error and I don't know how to correct.
Also, how do I later add to the URL, for example, I am trying

```
    class MyTest
{
    public string SpecialPart = "Excellent";

    public APIParamaters myParams = new APIParamaters
    {
        URL = URL + SpecialPart + "FirstCall",     //trying to do: "http://192.100.106.657:8811/some/part/here/version1/api/Excellent/FirstCall"
        SomethingElse = "Ok"
        //etc..
    };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path.Combine for URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372865/path-combine-for-urls)

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28418671/1997232) is duplicate for error you get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when compiling - 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Uri'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418671/error-when-compiling-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-string-to-system-uri)

Answer (score 3):

The following code means (cast this `string` as `System.Uri`) but string can not be cast as `System.Uri`:

```
(System.Uri) "http://192.100.106.657:8811/some/part/here/version1/api";
```

You should instantiate `System.Uri`:

```
public System.Uri URL { get; set; } = new System.Uri("http://192.100.106.657:8811/some/part/here/version1/api");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly. Any idea on how do I add parts at the end of it  (refering to the "public APIParamaters myParams = new APIParamaters" part of the question). Thank you very much !